# Android: Change icon of action share item on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I understand that this question has been asked here many times but after of spending hours searching for the solution I am unable to find one.

My requirement simple, I just want to change share icon on Action Bar to white color. I've the white drawables and using built-in Action Bar.

have tried setting icon in menu xml but didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share_white"
    android:title="@string/action_share"/>
```

Comment: What is your parent theme? If it is already one that supports a dark action bar (`Theme.Holo`, `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`, etc) then it will be changed automatically.

Comment: well, in that case there will be a gray drawable not white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `ShareActionProvider`'s `onCreateActionView()` method:

```
public View onCreateActionView() {
    // Create the view and set its data model.
    ...

    // Lookup and set the expand action icon.
    TypedValue outTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionModeShareDrawable, outTypedValue, true);
    Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(outTypedValue.resourceId);
    ...
```

So, to change this image, it looks like you should change the value of `actionModeShareDrawable` for your app's theme. Unfortunately this attribute seems not to be public in the framework (though it *is* if using AppCompat or ActionBarSherlock).

If you are using neither of these libraries, a possible solution is to create a subclass of `ShareActionProvider` and reimplement the `onCreateActionView()` method (though you'll have to duplicate its code and, possibly, the resources it uses).

Comment: It didn't work for me. Got following error...
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeShareDrawable'.

I think this attribute isn't public.

Comment: Looks like you're right. It seems to be public for appcompat-v7, but not in the standard R.attr. A pity. Well, you can always derive a class from ShareActionProvider and just override `onCreateActionView()`, but it's not so clean.

Comment: @Prashant edited the answer to reflect this. It's not as pretty but it should work.

Comment: I couldn't get any other way than creating my own class extending ShareActionProvider. It worked. I've marked your answer accepted as it pointed my to this solution :).
I've another requirement, probably you may give me a hint - Now I want to stop ShareActionProvider to display the last application icon, with content was shared, next to it. Thanks for your help so far.